# SendGrid API v3: Reply to a thread

Tags: c#, sendmail, .net-standard-2.0, sendgrid-api-v3, email-threading

I am trying to send an email as a reply to a previous thread using SendGrid v3 APIs. But it always shows as a new email thread in Outlook. I am using **"Message-ID", "In-Reply-To" and "References"** fields but it always fails to show under single thread. I am referring this thread [here](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs/issues/1158#issuecomment-968079098) to set the headers.

SendGrid document doesn't specify if v3 supports replying to previous thread or not. Any way to achieve email thread conversation is appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OKAY. I figured out the key here. I was missing **"<>"angled brackets** and looks like SendGrid takes it very seriously. So this is how headers section should look like.

```
"headers": {
    "Message-ID": "<11a7efc0-8f79-4569-a038-939b7b2b303@server.com>",
    "In-Reply-To": "<11a7efc0-8f79-4569-a038-939b7b2b301@server.com>",
    "References": "<11a7efc0-8f79-4569-a038-939b7b2b301@server.com>"
}
```

Checkout the angled brackets surrounding header values.

Comment: It's also picky about the `subject` field

Comment: Another scenario I recommend testing: Responding to forwarded emails and not just ones replied to.

Comment: Does anyone know where can I get the `message-id`? It's not included in the v3 API response,

Answer (score 0):

A was struggling with this same issue, so here is my solution overview - hope it helps!

**How do you find Message-ID in the first place?**

You can specify this when you send email via SendGrid 'send' API. Example POST call's JSON body could look like:

```
{"personalizations":[{"to":[{"email":"john.doe@example.com","name":"John Doe"}],"subject":"Email title"}],"content": [{"type": "text/plain", "value": "Heya!"}],"from":{"email":"myname@example.com","name":"myname"},"reply_to":{"email":"myname@example.com","name":"myname"},"headers": {
"Message-ID": "<Tk39zs7TRb6YBOydv7b0yQ@example.com>"}}
```

To be frank, I do not yet know the limitations for the "Message-ID" structure or formatting, but you can take a look at examples from other emails you receive e.g. in gmail "show original message" >> "Message-ID"

Now, when you want to send email as a reply to the previous one, your POST call's body could look like this:

```
{"personalizations":[{"to":[{"email":"john.doe@example.com","name":"John Doe"}],"subject":"Email title"}],"content": [{"type": "text/plain", "value": "This is my reply!"}],"from":{"email":"myname@example.com","name":"myname"},"reply_to":{"email":"myname@example.com","name":"myname"},"headers": {
"Message-ID": "<Tk39zs7TRb6YBOydv7b0yQ@example.com>",
"In-Reply-To": "<Tk39zs7TRb6YBOydv7b0yQ@example.com>",
"References": "<Tk39zs7TRb6YBOydv7b0yQ@example.com>"}}
```

Happy to hear more details/ideas around this!

P.S. A couple confusing things I ran into:

- SendGrid does not provide documentation around this!
- Message-ID is not the same as SendGrid's internal message ID, used for tracking email events and activity feed.
- Nor should you mix Message-ID with x-message-id, as I did, that you receive in API response's header when you send an email.

Best of luck!