# How to send an email through Sendgrid, as a reply to some email I received through Sendgrid inbound parse using Django?

Tags: python, django, email, sendgrid

So I am sending my email using sendgrid personalization something like this:

```
message = {
            "personalizations": context["personalizations"],
            "from": {"email": context["sender_email"]},
            "subject": context["subject"],
            "content": [{"type": MimeType.html, "value": context["body"]}],
            "reply_to": {"email": context["reply_to"]}
        }
sg = SendGridAPIClient(os.environ.get("SENDGRID_API_KEY"))
sg.send(message)
```

Here context["personalization"] is an object as below:

```
{
            "to": [{"email": applicant.email}],
            "custom_args": {
                "email_id": str(correspondance.id),
                "env": settings.ENVIRONMENT
            }
}
```

Sending and receiving the emails work fine. The problem is that I can't send an email as a reply to some email. Like a user sends me an email which I receive through sendgrid's inbound parse. Now I want to reply to the email I received.

A solution I found on the internet was that I have to add an 'in_reply_to' ID which I receive as Message_ID in inbound parse but that didn't work. I did something like this:

```
message = {
            "personalizations": context["personalizations"],
            "from": {"email": context["sender_email"]},
            "subject": context["subject"],
            "content": [{"type": MimeType.html, "value": context["body"]}],
            "reply_to": {"email": context["reply_to"]},
            "in_reply_to": message_id
        }
sg = SendGridAPIClient(os.environ.get("SENDGRID_API_KEY"))
sg.send(message)
```

Here the **message_id** is Message_ID I received in the inbound email's json.

Comment: Does this [previous question and answer help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70415956/sendgrid-api-v3-reply-to-a-thread)?

Comment: @philnash
I went through the answer. What I don't get is, how to add headers in my message. I did something like this:  
message["headers"] = { "In_Reply_To": "<#here comes message id>" }
But it doesn't work. Message is an object where I have the from, subject, content, reply_to, etc.

Comment: In [this example](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-python/blob/main/examples/helpers/mail_example.py) you set a header with `message.header = Header(“Header-Name”, “value”)`.

Comment: @philnash
Saw the code and understood it well. My problem is that I can't use the Mail( ) object for message as I have to do a lot of stuff with my message like adding attachments etc, which I don't know how to do with Mail( ). My message is just an object and not a Mail( ) object. So message.header won't work for me. Do I have another way where I can do something like message["headers"] = {"in_reply_to": "< >" } ????????

Comment: I would recommend looking into the example, there's a [kitchen sink function](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-python/blob/main/examples/helpers/mail_example.py#L137) that uses all of the options that you shows you how that works.

Comment: The title is very clear. Great job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What have worked best for me is setting the References header to an outbound mail to instruct email clients to create a thread.

Writers use References to indicate that a message has a parent. The last identifier in References identifies the parent. So the References header is a space   separated list of message IDs wrapped by <> in the following format:

"<MESSAGE_ID>"

You should check wether SendGrid already wraps the message you got from your inbound parse endpoint and then append it to the references string.

```py
import sendgrid
import os
from sendgrid.helpers.mail import Mail, Email, To, Content

previously_received_mail_id = "<abc@email.com>"

references = "" + previously_received_mail_id # empty in your case as its the first reply
sg = sendgrid.SendGridAPIClient(api_key=os.environ.get('SENDGRID_API_KEY'))
from_email = Email("test@example.com")  # Change to your verified sender
to_email = To("test@example.com")  # Change to your recipient
subject = "Sending with SendGrid is Fun"
content = Content("text/plain", "and easy to do anywhere, even with Python")
mail = Mail(from_email, to_email, subject, content)
mail.personalizations[0].add_header(Header("References",references))
# Get a JSON-ready representation of the Mail object
mail_json = mail.get()

# Send an HTTP POST request to /mail/send
response = sg.client.mail.send.post(request_body=mail_json)
print(response.status_code)
print(response.headers)
```

Comment: Saw the code and understood it well. My problem is that I can't use the Mail( ) object for message as I have to do a lot of stuff with my message like adding attachments etc, which I don't know how to do with Mail( ). My message is just an object and not a Mail( ) object. So message.header won't work for me. Do I have another way where I can do something like message["headers"] = {"in_reply_to": "< >" } ????????

Comment: Yes you should be able to do this in the following way  in your case `context["personalizations"][0]['headers']  = {"in_reply_to": "<message-id>" , "References": "<message-id-here-again>"}`

Comment: So I did exactly the way you told me. It just never works and the email is always sent as a new thread. I'm stuck at this and can't move forward an inch. Just before the message object in my code, I added this: 
context["personalizations"][0]['headers'] = {
            'in_reply_to': "<CABQc7oo0eSSKTBZ4xCfJEgi3iyKXbtDUG8Sm_qB=Ca04yMUiwQ@mail.gmail.com>"}
Looks good to me but doesn't work.

Comment: Try using the References header as indicated in the answer:
Example: context["personalizations"][0]['headers'] = { 'References': "<CABQc7oo0eSSKTBZ4xCfJEgi3iyKXbtDUG8Sm_qB=Ca04yMUiwQ@mail.gmail.com>"}

Comment: So I did it and added References and In-Reply-To in my headers. Fortunately, when I go to the 'Show Original' in Gmail, the headers really do have the References and In-Reply-To. However, it still never appends like a reply and always becomes a new thread. What am I doing wrong?? Is it about the subject of my reply email?